# Like/Recommend Shows link relative to www.facebook.com

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I have recommend buttons setup for articles in a blog. My OpenGraph meta tags are setup and checking the url on the facebook debugger shows the expected information (shown below obfuscated)

```
fb:app_id   xxx
og:url  http://example.com/blog/title-of-artilce
og:type article
og:title    Title of article
og:image    *correct image*
og:description  *description*
og:site_name    Sitename
og:updated_time 1326303278
```

However, in the user's wall, the image is not shown & the URL is shown relative to facebook:
http://www.facebook.com/blog/title-of-blog

The problem is identical whether the recommend is on the actual page, or located on a different page with a URL directing to the page. The 'like' count functions as expected.

The updated time above shows that it *shouldnt* be a cache problem.

Any help appreciated.

*** SOLVED *** - URL submitted to button was relative rather than absolute.

Comment: Good find on the relative URLs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake on my part.. The links in OG were not fully qualified URIs ..

So,  `/foo/bar`  was being translated to `http://facebook/foo/bar`